# access to query in model.php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

I have a relation and a function in my User.php;

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'level1_user_id')
            ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'level1_user_id']);
    }

    public function grandchildren()
    {
        return $this->children()->with(['grandchildren']);
    }
}
```

and this is my controller.php:

```
public function allChildren()
{
    $user = User::where('id', 3)->with(['grandchildren' =>
        function ($query) {
            $query->where('first_name', 'rose');
        }
    ])->first();
    return $user;
}
```

when I attach grandchildren it returns all nodes of that tree;
I want to assign a condition and get nodes that their name is 'rose', but I can do this just for first level; how can I access this query:

```
 $query->where('first_name', 'rose');
```

in my User.php in grandchildren function to set the query for others too?

I want to do sth like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'level1_user_id')
            ->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'level1_user_id']);
    }

    public function grandchildren(Query $inputQuery)
    {
        return $this->children()->with(['grandchildren' => function ($query) use ($inputQuery) {
        $query->$inputQuery;
    }]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! There seems to be a few striking anti-patterns with your implementation. First of all, I don't think you can really express parent-to-many-child relationships of users only using `users.level1_user_id`. Are you open for database schema improvements as part of an answer?

Comment: `level1_user_id` actually is `parent_id`; yes that's ok tell your comments about DB structure @Christian

Comment: I see, I thought `level1_user_id` represents the child user. Still I could suggest normalization techniques, but that's about it for database improvement. I'll try to answer your question next.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-)

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Models;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class User extends Model
{
    public function grandchildren()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(GrandChildren::class, Children::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your `users` table, with foreign key `level1_user_id` linking to other `users` instances in order to establish direct parental relationship, you could setup your `User` Laravel model as follows:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's direct children.
     */
    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'level1_user_id');
    }
}
```

Notice how we simply define how one `User` instance can be parent of other `User` instances. We don't mix in query logic, unlike how you use `->select()` and `->with()`. That's a good thing as it decouples your query concern from relationships' definitions.

Now in your controller, you can query a user while including its children, and while being able to customize the children's query, by doing the following:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

$user = User::with([
    'children' => function (Relation $query) {                               //  include children
        $query->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'level1_user_id']); //  only select the ff. columns on child users
    }
])->find(3);      //  shorthand of ->where('id', 3)->first()

$user->children;  //  now you have the collection of child users with the selected columns
```

To query a user, including all its grandchildren named "Rose", do:

```php
$user = User::with([
    'children' => function (Relation $query) {
        $query->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'level1_user_id']);
    },
    'children:children' => function (Relation $query) { //  customize query for grand children
        $query->where('first_name', 'Rose');
    }
])->find(3);

// grandchildren of $user can be accessed via $user->children[x]->children;
$allRoseGrandchild = $user->children->pluck('children')->flatten();
```

Answer (score 0):

In genealogy 1 `user_id` has 2 `parent_id` ...children and grandchildren are also just type of `User`.
It makes no sense to depend on any other  model, when model `User` has to depend on itself ...

Add one table `user_relations`, where the `parent_id` represents another `user_id`:

| user_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 7 | 6 |
| 8 | 5 |
| 8 | 6 |

Then this should become less complicated.